# Ionic Error: Unencoded

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, compiler-errors

I tried running the command:

“ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central”

But i got this error almost immediately:

Error: Unencoded <
Line: 79
Column: 2
Char: <
at error (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
at strictFail (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
at SAXParser.write (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1080:13)
at XMLParser.feed (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
at ElementTree.parse (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
at Object.parse (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:584:8)
at Function. (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/config.js:35:28)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (/Users/epics/Desktop/CAT_App/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
at

I saw in another post that someone had a similar error that was caused by a git merge error but my source code is up to date with what is on GitHub. Any help would be greatly appreciated, trying to get this error solved quickly.

Here is my config.xml file:

Comment: Do you have a `<3` in your `config.xml` / the XML files used by the plugin? If so, remove it.

Comment: There is not a <3 in my config.xml files but I don't know how to check through the XML files used by the plugin. Would it help if i posted my config.xml file?

Comment: Probably :) But really you're just looking for a `<` anywhere in an `.xml` file.

Comment: Alright Ill add it to my post